# Hours:Minutes:Seconds to Seconds

Tags: r, datetime-conversion

I am attempting to convert a long list of values in a column from Hours:Minutes:Seconds into just Seconds. The code I have below works fine as long as the values are in H:M:S format, but I have values in random rows that are just in the M:S format (so no hours). When I try to perform the below code on them, I obviously obtain an NA for each of those values. Is there a way that I can search for only the values in M:S format, and only the H:M:S format, and convert them separately? Do I need to add an hours value in each of the M:S values so I can convert all at once? My code below:

```
as.numeric(strptime(df$x, format="%H:%M:%S") - as.POSIXct(format(Sys.Date())), units="secs")

Example of data:
    Time
    12:22:05
    42:44

Example of data after running above:
    Time
    44525
    NA
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `parse_date_time` while using the `lubridate` package.

```
df$time <- parse_date_time(x = df$time, c("HMS","MS"))
```

Comment: Fyi, the goal is the number of seconds since midnight (apparent thanks to the OP's edit just now).

Comment: Thanks, I believe this should work. Will accept answer once I run it! I actually am looking for simply a H:M:S to S conversion, not just seconds since midnight. I have a few values that have the hours above 24, so thinking about the method I was previously using, those values wouldn't work too well.

Comment: `lubridate` has a function `period_to_seconds` that takes a time and returns the number of seconds in a day it represents. I'm slightly confused as to why you have time values that exceed `24`... are they not times but durations?

Answer (score 1):

Your proposal to add hours value to the M:S format seems also quite easy to implement :

```
x = c("12:22:05", "42:44")
x[nchar(x)<8] <- paste0("00:", x[nchar(x)<8])
as.numeric(strptime(x, format="%H:%M:%S") - as.POSIXct(format(Sys.Date())), units="secs")
## 44525  2564
```